# How to securely transfer data from Attribute to Action in asp-net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

So my use case is the following: I have created a custom Authorize attribute, which I use only on some specific actions and it works fine for me.
Now when someone is successfully authorized, I want to pass some parameters from the CustomAuthorizeAttribute to the called action. I get those parameters from the token, so they got to the authorize attribute securely.

```cs
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            // authorizes successfully
        }
    }
```

My initial idea was to 'hook' the parameters to HttpContext as headers, but I believe this isn't a secure way to transfer them at all.

Is there a way to transfer them, without the need to encrypt and then decrypt them in the action?

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [CustomAuthorize]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
```

Comment: Attributes have no data. They are static metadata emitted into the IL generated by the compiler. The authorization middleware sees that metadata and calls the `OnAuthorization` method of your type. The context you need (and have) is `HttpActionContext`

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "secure"?

Comment: By secure, I mean that I don't want the data to get stolen. Like phone number. Your question is good, thinking more about it, it seems there is no way without encrypting the data. My question then is how to transfer the encrypted data to the action in the best way.

Comment: Attribute and action are both on the server so there is no way someone can see whats happening there unless someone can sneak into the server. So encryption is an overkill there. If you are authorizing the user before he/she can access a particular controller action, then you pretty much know who the user is in the action method.  So instead of passing data from attribute to action, you should retrieve the data about the user from database in the action itself.

Comment: If your custom authorize attribute sets a Principal with something like a ClaimsIdentity, then you might be able to create your own "Identity Type" which also contains the values you decrypted from the token. Then in the controller you should have access to this principal object?

Comment: That could do the trick I believe, if you want, post an answer with some code (could be pseudo code) I'll try it later or tomorrow and will approve you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to create your own Principal type, which implements `IPrincipal`, or extend an existing principal type, like `ClaimsPrincipal`.

Then in your `CustomAuthorizationAttribute` code, you can set your properties from the decrypted token. Once back in the controller you should be able to access the principal, and retrieve those values which you have set.

References:
[IPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.iprincipal?view=netframework-4.8), [Claims Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.iprincipal?view=netframework-4.8)

Pseudo code, based loosely on ClaimsPrincipal as I have used that before.

```
public class CustomPrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    public CustomPrincipal(IEnumerable<ClaimsIdentity> identities, string phone)
         : base(identities)
    {
        this.PhoneNumber = phone;
    }

    // My properties that I need.
    public string PhoneNumber { get; }
}

public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        ... other code ...

        context.Principal = new CustomPrincipal( <stuff to set> );

    }
}
```

Then in your controller actions which are authorized:

```
CustomPrincipal principal = this.RequestContext.Principal as CustomPrincipal;
... use principal.PhoneNumber etc ...
```